# PL/SQL: ORA-12704: character set mismatch when insert varchar2 to nvarchar2

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I try to populate a table TBL in a loop. And get `ORA-12704: character set mismatch` on a subquery. 
Here is a query I use:

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (SELECT t.Stuff FROM STUFF_TABLE t ORDER BY t.Name ASC)
  LOOP
  INSERT INTO TBL(StuffId, StuffName)
          VALUES(
            i.Stuff,
            (SELECT TempStuffName FROM 
                (SELECT COALESCE(st.StuffName, i.Stuff) as TempStuffName FROM STUFFDEFINITION st WHERE st.Stuff = i.Stuff ORDER BY st.Version DESC)
             WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
          );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

The columns types are the following:

```
STUFF_TABLE.Stuff nvarchar2(30)
TBL.StuffId nvarchar2(30)
TBL.StuffName nvarchar2(50)
STUFFDEFINITION.Stuff varchar2(255)
STUFFDEFINITION.StuffName varchar2(255)
```

The issue, as I understand it, is in type casting namely from varchar2(255) to nvarchar2(50).
I tried to use CAST, Translate functions, but it didn't help. The `ORA-12704: character set mismatch` still occurs.

Is there a way to populate TBL in a loop as I try it to do?

Below is the test data to reproduce issue I talk about:

```
CREATE TABLE STUFF_TABLE
(
  Stuff nvarchar2(30),
  Name nvarchar2(50)
);

CREATE TABLE TBL
(
  StuffId nvarchar2(30),
  StuffName nvarchar2(50)
);

CREATE TABLE STUFFDEFINITION
(
  Stuff varchar2(255),
  StuffName varchar2(255),
  Version number(19)
)

INSERT INTO STUFF_TABLE(Stuff, Name) VALUES('First', 'Name1');
INSERT INTO STUFF_TABLE(Stuff, Name) VALUES('Second', 'Name2');
INSERT INTO STUFF_TABLE(Stuff, Name) VALUES('Third', 'Name3');

INSERT INTO STUFFDEFINITION(Stuff, StuffName, Version) VALUES('First', 'First Stuff', 1);
INSERT INTO STUFFDEFINITION(Stuff, StuffName, Version) VALUES('First', 'First Stuff', 2);
INSERT INTO STUFFDEFINITION(Stuff, StuffName, Version) VALUES('Second', 'Second Stuff', 1);
INSERT INTO STUFFDEFINITION(Stuff, StuffName, Version) VALUES('Third', 'Third Stuff', 1);
```

Comment: Perhaps you're after `to_nchar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your statement its clear that you are joining a `varchar2` column with `nvarchar2` and inserting a `varchar2` column to a `nvarchar2` column. You need to do a conversion first. Try this:

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (SELECT t.Stuff FROM STUFF_TABLE t ORDER BY t.Name ASC)
  LOOP
  INSERT INTO TBL(StuffId, StuffName)
          VALUES(
                 i.Stuff,
                    (SELECT to_nchar(TempStuffName) 
                       FROM 
                        (SELECT COALESCE(to_nchar(st.StuffName), i.Stuff) as TempStuffName 
                         FROM STUFFDEFINITION st 
                         WHERE to_nchar(st.Stuff) = i.Stuff 
                         ORDER BY st.Version DESC)
                     WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
               );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: I tried TO_NCHAR and it didn't help. But now I understood what I was doing wrong - I had to cast st.StuffName and st.Stuff also. It works as expected.  And thanks for the explanation of my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use PL/SQL:

```
INSERT INTO TBL ( StuffId, StuffName )
SELECT TO_NCHAR( t.stuff ),
       TO_NCHAR(
         COALESCE(
           MAX( d.StuffName ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY d.version ),
           t.stuff
         )
       )
FROM   StuffTable t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN StuffDefinition d
       ON ( t.stuff = TO_NCHAR( d.stuff ) )
GROUP BY t.stuff;
```

Comment: This example is simple version of a real query. There's also entry creation in another table in a real query, newly created entry id is stored to a variable that is stored in TBL also. Perhaps I had to point it also.

Comment: Table columns are of differnt datatype. The above one will still throw error.

Comment: @XING - Added a conversion.

Comment: Still missing a conversion on join `ON ( t.stuff = d.stuff )`

Answer (score 0):

Oracle says this about that error: 'A string expression in the VALUES clause of an INSERT statement does not have the same character set as the column into which the value would be inserted.'

Please select from nls_database_parameters and tell me what the values of these are:
NLS_CHARACTERSET
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS